# Google Maps в Swing

Tags: java, swing

Приветствую! Столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно отобразить Google карту в моем Swing приложении. Единственные задачи - устанавливать маркеры (правда в большом объеме) и передвигать камеру к маркерам. Возможно, в будущем нужно будет прокладывать линии вдоль дорог.

---

Поискав в интернете я нашел следующие библиотеки для решения моей задачи:

[JxMapViewer2](https://github.com/msteiger/jxmapviewer2) - бесплатная библиотека, но напрягает ее "новизна" (где-то видел упоминания даже 2009-го года).

[JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) - реализация браузера, через который все можно сделать. Однако, это платно для коммерческих проектов, коим мой и является (денег, естественно, нет).

---

Какие есть альтернативные библиотеки для Swing'a, которые помогут отобразить карту (с маркерами и линиями). Возможно есть какие-то другие варианты для решения моей задачи?

P.S. Если у Вас есть варианты только для JavaFX, предлагайте в ответ. Потом это все равно переписывать под него. Ответ не приму, вопрос про Swing, но плюсик поставлю :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда-то решал подобную задачу с отображением Yandex карт. Самое адекватное что мне удалось найти это [SWT Browser](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fbrowser%2FBrowser.html), только это не Swing, а SWT, зато работает как надо. Ни один из опробованных мной компонентов на Swing не отображает страницу корректно.

Comment: Бось данный вариант для меня не подойдет. Все окно уже на Swing, очень много элементов и написана логика заполнения элементов. Под саму карту оставлено одну `JPanel`. Но плюс, конечно же, поставлю.

Comment: Swing и SWT можно использовать совместно.

Comment: То есть можно "браузер" использовать как компонент.

Comment: Использование Swing компонент в SWT приложении вообще не вызывает ни проблем ни вопросов. А про то как использовать SWT компоненты в Swing JFrame/JPanel в интернете полно статей и рекомендаций, тут чуть-чуть посложнее, но вполне решаемо.

Comment: Только что добрался до этой задачи. Большое спасибо, все прекрасно работает! Осталось только разобраться, как убрать из карты вообще все, что можно. Как я понял, она попросту не поддерживает динамическую загрузку (которая стартует при любом действии), поэтому нельзя давать пользователю двигать\клацать карту.

Comment: По поводу Goole Maps ничего не скажу, но с Yandex.Карты у меня всё работало. Я загружал в этот броузер самостоятельно снегерённую страницу с JavaScript - всё двигалось, масштабировалось и т.п. Ещё у Яндекса есть вариант с off-line режимом, когда по запросу к серверу возвращается кусок карты в виде картинки, вот тогда да - уже ничего с ним не сделаешь. Может быть аналогичный случай?

Comment: Просмотрю API Google Map'a, что-то должно быть. В крайнем случае, перейду на Яндекс.Карты, если они понимаю инструкции по построению путей.